# How do I detect preloaded images that haven't been attached to the page using HtmlUnit?

Tags: image, htmlunit

I'm loading some page content using HtmlUnit, and I would like to be able to capture the URLs of images created in the following fashion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'slider.png';
</script>
```

The key issue here is that the image is never attached to the document, so I can't find it by iterating over 'img' tags.  Furthermore, HtmlUnit does not actually generate a web request for the image (as it shouldn't), so I can't pick it up by overriding the WebConnection and intercepting the request.

In a normal browser, the image would be preloaded when the src attribute is set.  If an image would normally be loaded, I want to be able to tell that that would happen.

My constraint is that I do not control the content, so I can't just load the image differently.  The content comes from a 3rd party, and I am validating it and recording anomalies.  I prefer not to gather this information via a different tool, since HtmlUnit is doing a lot of other tasks for me already.